# syslog with strings?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, syslog

Trying to write out `syslog` entries containing strings but they don't register.

```
// person.name is an NSSTring
syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "Some string %@", person.name);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `syslog` has no idea what an Objective-C object is. You have to convert it to a C-style string.

```
syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "Some string %s", [person.name UTF8String]);
```

Effectively, `syslog` is just a C function. It lives in another world from `NSString`.